# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined Nodejs Mysql Query result

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-modules

This error doesn't happen always , but it's been happening frequently and i couldn't find any solution for it. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: the table in the database has the 'title' column and there are data in there.

**The Code :**

```
 async function selectNotificationData(control_message_id){
const sql = await new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    let query = "SELECT title, body ,url_push, img_push, url_type, status,silent,channel FROM control_message WHERE id_control_message =?";
    con.query(query, [control_message_id],(err,row)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        let n =row[0];
        let pf=null;
        try{
            pf =  setPerFlagOptmized(n.title,n.body);
            res({not_data:n,pf})
        }
        catch (err) {

            console.log("[Row : "+row[0]+"]");
            console.log("[n : "+n+"]");
            console.log("ERROR IN SELECTING NOT DATA OR SETTING THE FLAG : "+err);
        }


    })
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log("ERROR IN SELECTING Notification DATA : "+error);
});
```

**The Error :**

```
app_1    | /usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
app_1    |       throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
app_1    |       ^
app_1    |
app_1    | TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
app_1    |     at Query.con.query (/usr/src/app/v4/message/controllers/expandWorker.js:669:57)
app_1    |     at Query.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
app_1    |     at Query._callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
app_1    |     at Query.Sequence.end 
(/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
app_1    |     at Query._handleFinalResultPacket 
(/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:149:8)
app_1    |     at Query.EofPacket 
(/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:133:8)
app_1    |     at Protocol._parsePacket 
(/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
app_1    |     at Parser._parsePacket 
(/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
app_1    |     at Parser.write (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
app_1    |     at Protocol.write (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
```

**I tried to log**

```
[Row : undefined]
[n : undefined]
```

The **setPerFlagOptmized** function :

```
 function setPerFlagOptmized(title,body){
    var t = (title.includes("|*") || title.includes("*|") || title.includes("{{") || title.includes("}}"));
    var b = (body.includes("|*") || body.includes("*|") || body.includes("{{") || body.includes("}}"));
    return (t || b) ? 1:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens when no record is found for the given query.
`err` in the callback will not be defined in this case,  instead `row` is just an empty array.

Since you don't have a check for that and directly access `row[0]`, which yields `undefined`, the error is thrown for `n.title`. So you should add the following check:

```
if(err) throw err;

if (!row.length) {
   // handle error - throw or return here
}
// ..rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i'll try that , would it be that the query faced a lock timeout and returned nothing ?

Comment: Good question, but I think the err in the callback would be defined in those cases.

Comment: i guess i need to check the databse if it's throwing the innodb lock info or not  ,
does this affect  "innodb_print_lock_wait_timeout_info" ?

Comment: Hmm ok, honestly I'm not sure here :/ let's see .. maybe someone else has an idea. sorry :/

Comment: it's okay mate , thank you so much for trying to help